# Unable to install R pmml package on Red Hat

Tags: r, pmml

Trying to install pmml package using R Studio on Red Hat. I get the following output:

```
================================================
downloaded 136 KB

* installing *source* package 'pmml' ...
** package 'pmml' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** data
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error : object 'str_interp' is not exported by 'namespace:stringr'
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ?pmml?
* removing '/usr/lib64/R/library/pmml'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package 'pmml' had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: What version of `stringr` you have? Looks like it's outdated. Try installing 
new `stringr` first.

Comment: that resolved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: If it solves the issue - I have posted as an answer. Please, mark it as an answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have outdated `stringr` package. Install the new `stringr` package from CRAN with:

```
install.packages(c("stringr"))
```